# How to get part of a linestring that is less than 300 meters apart from another linestring?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I've two linestrings Line1,Line2. I'm trying to get the part of Line1 that is 300m apart from line2.

```
line1 = "LINESTRING(72.863221 18.782499,72.863736 18.770147,72.882275 18.756169,72.881417 18.750805,72.878842 18.736987,72.874379 18.709512,72.860989 18.679593,72.864422 18.653897)"
line2 = "LINESTRING(72.883133 18.780793,72.882103 18.760314,72.862534 18.716422,72.860474 18.683577)"
```

I used the `ST_DWithin` function but it returns the whole linestring if the distance is lesser than 300 meters. Here's my query:

```
road2 = "ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;%s')"%line1
road4 = "ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;%s')"%line2
cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(road1) from %s as road1,%s as road2 
            where ST_DWithin(road1,road2,500)"%(road2,road4))
res = cur.fetchall()
print res
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of ST_Intersection/ ST_Buffer and ST_DWITHIN:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LINES;
CREATE TABLE LINES(gid serial, geom geometry(LINESTRING,4326));
INSERT INTO LINES (geom) VALUES(
(ST_SETSRID(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(72.863221 18.782499,72.863736 18.770147,72.882275 18.756169,72.881417 18.750805,72.878842 18.736987,72.874379 18.709512,72.860989 18.679593,72.864422 18.653897)'),4326))),
(
(ST_SETSRID(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(72.883133 18.780793,72.882103 18.760314,72.862534 18.716422,72.860474 18.683577)'),4326))
);


-- visualizing Buffer
INSERT INTO LINES (geom) VALUES(
(
SELECT ST_Transform(ST_Exteriorring(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(geom,32643),300)),4326) from LINES where gid=2)
);



-- Intersection

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Intersection;

CREATE TABLE Intersection(gid serial, geom geometry(MULTILINESTRING,4326));

INSERT INTO Intersection (geom) VALUES(

(
select 
    st_transform(
      st_intersection(
        line1.geom, 
        st_buffer(ST_Transform(line2.geom,32643),300))
      ,
      4326) as geom

from 
  (SELECT ST_Transform(geom,32643) as geom from lines where gid=1) as line1, 
  (SELECT ST_Transform(geom,32643) as geom from lines where gid=2) as line2

where 
  st_dwithin(line1.geom, line2.geom, 300) 
 )
  );
```

[image]